# How to find 'common route' in Google Maps?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary

given 2 users

- A
- B

and 2 journeys

- A goes from X to Y
- B goes from J to Z

is it possible to find a common route in Google Maps? 
What sort of algorithm can I use to discover similar journeys?

EDIT: i try to be more accurate: for common route, i mean part they can travel togheter.

Comment: What do you mean by "a common route"? What counts as similar?

Comment: You mean the part they could travel together?

Comment: Yes, i mean part they could travel togheter.

Comment: Do you just want to know if two existing routes have parts in common, or do you want to figure out how to build two routes that have parts in common?

Comment: Hi Lasse, i would like to know if two existing routes have parts in common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you need is something similiar to Dijikstras algorithm. Use this to build a graph and then compare them to find the common path